# python pip install poster gives me error --> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\

Tags: python, poster

I am using Python 3, and am not able to --> pip install poster library

I am trying to upload a file using poster.  I have tried: pip install poster or easy_install poster they both fail I get an error :

```
print "send:", repr(value)
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\...

pip install poster  also tried   

easy_install poster .
```

I have also tried downloading .tar.gz and I get the same error

```
I have also tried : pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: HTTP Post a large file with streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502596/python-http-post-a-large-file-with-streaming) - this appears to have the same behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the first line of code, it seems like `poster` is only Python 2 compatible. Notice that [the latest version of this library was published in 2011](https://pypi.org/project/poster/#history), so Python 3 compatibility was probably not implemented.

Try using a different library or switching to Python 2.

Comment: Do you know what library I can use to upload a file in pyhton 3?

Comment: I'm really not sure, [this post might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40015869/how-to-stream-post-data-into-python-requests). Are the files you are uploading too big to load into memory? If they are not, you can just use the standard `requests` library [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22567306/python-requests-file-upload).

Answer (score 0):

Use [poster3](https://libraries.io/pypi/poster3).

It is the Python3 version of poster.

Answer (score 0):

For Python3 use poster3. refer [this](https://pypi.org/project/poster3/)

```
pip install poster3
```